# Elementary course on exterior differential calculus

Tags: differential-forms, differential, exterior-derivative

I am looking for a bibliographic source for a course on external differential calculus that is accessible at a very "low level" in university; first or second year of university in physics and chemistry; no more. Is there a course that very simply introduces the notions of external differential calculus, in the least formal way possible mathematically and in the most quickly exploitable and understandable almost intuitively.
Included in this course are the Frobenius theorem and the non-integrable differentiable systems according to this theorem .

Thank you in advance

Comment: To confirm, you are looking for a reference that only assumes (classical) multivariable calculus?

Comment: Hello Rollen, Yes, essentially multivariate differential calculus and vector exterior product calculus in a relatively light version for students with a first or second year university level and little mathematics. It is quite difficult to find a way to teach this external differential calculus at an elementary level of mathematics and yet it would be very interesting for many things: Frobenius theorem among others.